# combing awk commands + adding column values and column name

Tags: csv, awk

I want to add a 5th column to this csv file

```
$ head countries_int_code.csv
country,latitude,longitude,name
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola
```

this adds the values to the column

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1 {$5="Unknown"}1' OFS=, countries_int_code.csv > countries_int_code2.csv

$ head countries_int_code2.csv
country,latitude,longitude,name
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,Unknown
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,Unknown
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,Unknown
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,Unknown
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,Unknown
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,Unknown
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,Unknown
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,Unknown
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,Unknown
```

This gives the column its name

```
$ awk -F, 'NR<=1 {$5="ColName"}1' OFS=, countries_int_code2.csv > countries_int_code3.csv


$ head countries_int_code3.csv
country,latitude,longitude,name,ColName
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,Unknown
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,Unknown
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,Unknown
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,Unknown
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,Unknown
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,Unknown
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,Unknown
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,Unknown
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,Unknown
```

Instead of writing to various files I could just use a tmpfile to write to and then rename it to the original.
`... countries_int_code.csv > tmpfile && mv tmpfile countries_int_code.csv`

**But can i combine the 2 awk commands above into the 1 command to do it all, so I can add column values and column name in 1 command?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $0, (NR>1?"Unknown":"ColName")}' file
country,latitude,longitude,name,ColName
AD,42.546245,1.601554,Andorra,Unknown
AE,23.424076,53.847818,United Arab Emirates,Unknown
AF,33.93911,67.709953,Afghanistan,Unknown
AG,17.060816,-61.796428,Antigua and Barbuda,Unknown
AI,18.220554,-63.068615,Anguilla,Unknown
AL,41.153332,20.168331,Albania,Unknown
AM,40.069099,45.038189,Armenia,Unknown
AN,12.226079,-69.060087,Netherlands Antilles,Unknown
AO,-11.202692,17.873887,Angola,Unknown
```

Comment: tks, could you kindly just give a brief breakdown of the parameters?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I just combined your examples but used a ternary expression to decide what to print at the end of each line instead of unnecessarily assigning to a 5th field.